# Regular expression in C++ that can look ahead?

Tags: c++, regex, regex-lookarounds

Using C++ regex with the default modified ECMAScript grammar, is there a simple regular expression which will distinguish

```
an.RAd    // not allowed (changed by edit)
abn.RAd   // allowed
an.IPd    // allowed
abn.IPd   // not allowed
```

where `a`, `b` and `d` are regular expressions, and the period and upper-case letters are literal. Whether `b` can be present depends on the characters following the period.

Here is what I have tried:

```
^a((?!.*\.IPd$)b)n\.(IP|RA)d$
```

The negative lookahead is supposed to detect test strings not ending in `IPd`. The result is only `abn.RAd` is allowed. I also expected `an.IPd` to be allowed, but it does not match, and I don't understand why.

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/xpressive.html

Comment: `a(?:b?\.RA|\.IP)d`? [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DdDIZ4/1/).

Comment: @Jarod42: Your soln works, but I got the original requirements wrong. I fixed that in the Q, and posted an attempt to use lookahead, which doesn't work.

Comment: Then `a(?:bn\.RA|n\.IP)d` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZLhsr5/1)

Comment: @Jarod42: Yes, that should do it. Because my example is part of a larger regex, and because the regex b, n and d are complex, I was hoping for a solution that did not repeat these. I was able to do so, at the cost of repeating the lookahead condition `^a((?!.*\.ip2$)b|(?=.*\.ip2$))n\.(ra|ip)2$`. Any suggestions how that condition can appear only once?